# Openstack - Windows images based on qcow2 file starts 80% full? Resizing is not working?

Tags: image, virtual-machine, virtualization, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to set up a Windows 7 instance on Openstack. This instance requires at least 50 GB of free disk space to run an application. When I create my windows 7 image and upload it everything works fine, except for one problem - The disk space is already 80% used when I start.

For example a windows 7 instance with a 100GB hard drive has only 18.3GB of free space.

**What I tried:**

I have been trying to create a windows 7 image with a 100GB hard drive. I created a QCOW2 file with a windows 7 ISO and the Virt-IO drivers ISO using the below commands:

create the empty qcow2 file:

> qemu-img create -f qcow2 win_64bit_SP1_100GB.qcow2 100G

Combine the two ISOs:

> sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system   --name
>   PS4Agent_win7_64bit_SP1_100GB --ram 2048 --vcpus 2   --network
>   network=default,model=virtio   --disk
>   path=win_64bit_SP1_100GB.qcow2,format=qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio
>   --cdrom /home/khennessy/win7_win8_iso_creation/SW_DVD5_Win_Pro_7w_SP1_64BIT_English_-2_MLF_X17-59279.ISO
>   --disk path=/home/khennessy/win7_win8_iso_creation/virtio-win-0.1-100.iso,device=cdrom
>   --vnc --os-type windows --os-variant win2k8 --force

I then uploaded these to Openstack using a 'minimum disk space' of 90GB, making the minimum flavor xl. (Currently trying a lower value, the images are so large it takes a long time to test anything.)

I then create an instance using this image and log into it using the 'console' view. It all works fine but when I go into 'my computer' it tells me I have only 18GB free space? I have tried 'resizing' the images but it just seems to bring them into an error state?

Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

Before you upload your windows 7 image onto glance, you need to download CloudbaseInitSetup_x64.msi
 or CloudbaseInitSetup_x86.msi] and install it on your windows7 image first. Also, don't forget to add "plugins=cloudbaseinit.plugins.windows.extendvolumes.ExtendVolumesPlugin" to the configuration file of Cloudbase-init.
You can visit and http://cloud-ninja.org/2014/05/14/running-windows-7-guests-on-openstack-icehouse/ for more information.